# rmarkdown help for bmatrix error ! Missing $ inserted

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I am having an issue in rmarkdown when knitting to pdf. The script works when I knit to html, but get I an error when I try to knit to pdf. Below is the script:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_{1,1} &\cdots &Y_{1,m} \\
Y_{2,1} &\cdots &Y_{2,m}  \\
\vdots  &\ddots &\vdots \\
Y_{n, 1} &... &Y_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix} \text{=} 

\begin{bmatrix}
1 &X_{1,1} &\cdots &X_{1,p} \\
1 &X_{2,1} &\cdots &X_{2,p}  \\
\vdots  &\vdots  &\ddots &\vdots \\
1 &X_{n, 1}  &\cdots &X_{n,p}
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1,1} &\cdots &B_{1,m} \\
B_{2,1} &\cdots &B_{2,m}  \\
\vdots  &\ddots &\vdots \\
B_{n, 1} &\cdots &B_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix} \text{+}

\begin{bmatrix}
\varepsilon_{1,1} &\cdots &\varepsilon_{1,m} \\
\varepsilon_{2,1} &\cdots &\varepsilon_{2,m}  \\
\vdots  &\ddots  &\vdots \\
\varepsilon_{n, 1} &\cdots &\varepsilon_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

The error message I get is

```
<inserted text> 
                $
l.273 
You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r ` in ms.Rmd
```

Comment: Hmmm, works fine when I plug it [in here](https://quicklatex.com/). So it's not LaTeX syntax issue.

Comment: Thanks. Have to figure out what the issue is then

Comment: You need to remove the blank lines between the matrix definitions.  R Markdown can sometimes handle raw LaTeX, but it makes a lot of changes, and those spaces cause problems.   I suspect the blank lines make it treat each block separately, but they are really one big block.

Comment: Removing the blank lines worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a fragment of LaTeX:  a single block beginning with `\begin{equation}` on the first line and ending with `\end{equation}` on the last line.  That's legal as Markdown source (because anything is legal as Markdown source!), but it isn't being transformed into a complete `.tex` document properly.

I suspect Pandoc is transforming each group of lines separately, i.e. the three blank lines cause it to be treated as four blocks of LaTeX, which is incorrect.  It adds additional code around each of those blocks and that leads to the error.

A workaround is simply to leave out the blank lines, though that makes it harder to read.  Another choice is to put LaTeX comment markers (`%`) on each of them, i.e. change to

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_{1,1} &\cdots &Y_{1,m} \\
Y_{2,1} &\cdots &Y_{2,m}  \\
\vdots  &\ddots &\vdots \\
Y_{n, 1} &... &Y_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix} \text{=} 
%
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &X_{1,1} &\cdots &X_{1,p} \\
1 &X_{2,1} &\cdots &X_{2,p}  \\
\vdots  &\vdots  &\ddots &\vdots \\
1 &X_{n, 1}  &\cdots &X_{n,p}
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1,1} &\cdots &B_{1,m} \\
B_{2,1} &\cdots &B_{2,m}  \\
\vdots  &\ddots &\vdots \\
B_{n, 1} &\cdots &B_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix} \text{+}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
\varepsilon_{1,1} &\cdots &\varepsilon_{1,m} \\
\varepsilon_{2,1} &\cdots &\varepsilon_{2,m}  \\
\vdots  &\ddots  &\vdots \\
\varepsilon_{n, 1} &\cdots &\varepsilon_{n,m}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```